# Change QWizard buttons size

Tags: qt, qwidget

I am trying to do something that looks easy, but I cannot make it working.  I want to make buttons bigger in my QWizard.  Here is the code :

```
#include "wizard.h"
#include "ui_wizard.h"
#include "QAbstractButton"
Wizard::Wizard(QWidget *parent) :
    QWizard(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Wizard)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QRect rect = this->button(QWizard::NextButton)->geometry();
    this->button(QWizard::NextButton)->setGeometry(rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width(), 40);

    rect = this->button(QWizard::CancelButton)->geometry();
    this->button(QWizard::CancelButton)->setGeometry(rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width(), 40);

    rect = this->button(QWizard::BackButton)->geometry();
    this->button(QWizard::BackButton)->setGeometry(rect.x(), rect.y(), rect.width(), 40);

}

Wizard::~Wizard()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

This code does nothing.  Is it possible to change the geometry of the buttons?  Or it is forbidden?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better is to customize user interface using QSS (Qt Style Sheet). You can read your qss file and setup stylesheet for the whole application using [QApplication::setStyleSheet()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop).

Also you can setup qss programmatically (not the best practics).

```
setStyleSheet("QAbstractButton { height: 50px }");
```

What sets height for all buttons on the widget.

In the worst case you can try this:

```
button(QWizard::CancelButton)->setStyleSheet("height: 50px");
```

Comment: Actually, just discovered that when my QWizard is in AeroStyle, setStyleSheet does not work.  setStyleSheet works for all buttons with modernStyle.  Any idea?